# Count duplicate numbers inside of foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Basically, I am fetching data from an API and that API has duplicate numbers. I want to count the duplicate numbers within the `foreach`, but its not working for some reason. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. You can see there is `33` many times. See the picture how it prints. It should be showing something like this

```
Array
(
    [33] => 5
    [2] => 3
)
```

**Code:**

```
foreach ($parsed_json1->numbers as $item) {
    $ui = $item->no;
    $currentp= number_format($ui, 6);
    //echo $currentp;
    //echo "</br>";

    $array = array($currentp);
    $vals = array_count_values($array);
   //echo 'No. of NON Duplicate Items: '.count($vals).'<br><br>';
    print_r($vals);
}
```

[image]

Comment: If the `$parsed_json1->numbers` is an array, you do not need to `foreach()` through it as the `array_count_values()` function does all that you need already. Have you tried printing `array_count_values($parsed_json1->numbers)` instead of the `foreach()` loop?

Comment: @Palo `$parsed_json1->numbers` is an array of objects, not an array of numbers.

Comment: @Barmar yes, you are right, Usman was not very clear about that. 
But the idea is the same, just to extract the numbers to an array of numbers, as seen below.

Comment: @Palo I thought it was clear from `$ui = $item->no;`. So the `foreach` loop is still needed, to extract the numbers to an array.

Comment: @Barmar, sure it was to you :-). I overlooked that line for my first comment, when I saw the incorrect use of `array_count_values()`, which was obviously not used right. 
I am really not a php-man, but you could get rid of `foreach`, if you make use of `array_map()`, for instance, couldn't you?

Comment: @Palo Of course, but that's just another way to loop. At some point you need to code a loop to get all the numbers out of the array of objects, you can't just use `array_count_values()` directly.

Comment: @Barmar, so does `array_count_values()` contains a loop, so what? :-) 
Has it not become obvious to you that it is obvious to me? :-)

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental flaw of your code is that you take **one value** and format it, then you **put it into array** and then do **`array_count_values`** on it.

See the difference:

```
$arr = [33, 32, 23, 33, 22, 23, 32, 33, 33];

print_r(array_count_values($arr));

foreach($arr as $a) {
    $currentp= number_format($a, 6);
    $array = array($currentp);
    $vals = array_count_values($array);
    print_r($vals);

}
```

First `print_r` prints:

```
Array
(
    [33] => 4
    [32] => 2
    [23] => 2
    [22] => 1
)
```

And the `print_r` inside `foreach` prints:

```
Array([33.000000] => 1)
Array([32.000000] => 1)
Array([23.000000] => 1)
Array([33.000000] => 1)
Array([22.000000] => 1)
Array([23.000000] => 1)
Array([32.000000] => 1)
Array([33.000000] => 1)
Array([33.000000] => 1)
```

Do you realize the difference?

I guess, what you need is

```
$arr = (array_count_values([33, 32, 23, 33, 22, 23, 32, 33, 33]));
$new_arr = [];

foreach($arr as $k => $a) {
    $new_arr[number_format($k, 6)] = $a;
}

print_r($new_arr);
```

Which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [33.000000] => 4
    [32.000000] => 2
    [23.000000] => 2
    [22.000000] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you use `number_format()`, but I'm guessing you need something like this

```
$num_array = []; // Initialize number array
foreach ($parsed_json1->numbers as $item) {
    $ui = $item->no;
    $currentp= number_format($ui, 6);
    $num_array[] = $currentp; // Store each number first to number array
}
// After foreach loop, do array_count_values to number array
$vals = array_count_values($num_array);
print_r($vals); //Print result
```